# WPF Mvvm ScrollViewer Event Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I tried to bind ScrollChanged Event.. this is part of xaml codes.(MvvmLight)

```
<customevent:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged">
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ScrollChangeCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                    </customevent:RoutedEventTrigger>
```

I have to receive object of arguments. So that, I tried to..
Part of ViewModel codes.

```
if (obj.ExtentHeightChange != 0 || obj.ExtentWidthChange != 0)
            {
                ScrollViewer temp = (ScrollViewer)obj.Source;
                Grid tempG = (Grid)temp.Content;
```

It worked. But I think that there is a better way to get sender through event and which is more adaptive for Mvvm Pattern.

How to get event argument and event sender with binding?

Comment: Hi, I don't see what you are doing with the scrollViewer and the grid after, but you must not use UIElement in the viewmodel ! (this is not mvvm...) - would better to manage the event in the view and change values in the viewmodel.

Comment: @GCamel Thank you for reply. :) I get mouseevent argument e.getposition(UIElement). So I need to access xaml object of view.

Comment: I think GCamel's point was that UI elements are specific to a view implementation.  View Models should not be tied to a particular view implementation.  Thus, the appropriate place to put this code is in the view's code-behind, not the view model.  Don't try to shoehorn all your UI code into the 'VM' in 'MVVM'.

Comment: implement ScrollChanged event in the view; get the position and update the viewmodel ( (this.datacontext as MyViewModel).Position = e.getposition(); )